# How can get records after specific id in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

We have this on mysql:

[image]

**And want return with 2 limit:**

    1- `"SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY point DESC LIMIT 0,2"` //return 'google' & 'jsfiddle'

    2- `"SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY point DESC LIMIT 2,2"` //return 'stackoverflow' & 'msn'

    3- `"INSERT INTO table SET id = 11, name = 'gmail', point = 101 "`

    4- `"SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY point DESC LIMIT 4,2"` //return 'msn' & 'emra'

**in number 4 'msn' is duplicate. I want number 4 return 'emra' & 'facebook'.**

I can save 'id' and I want query that return records after that id.

**[EDIT]**
**let me ask in another way:**

we have this records:

```
id, name, point
4, 'google', 100
6, 'yahoo', 100
3, 'gmail', 100
8, 'ymail', 100
2, 'fb', 100
```

I have id:3 and want select records that are after this id(in this example 'ymail', 'fb')

this is a ajax load content by scorlling(like facebook) but about max points of users that every moment is changing.

Comment: how at number 4 msn is duplicate? why facebook?? why not bing, github?? I don't get your question

Comment: **you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11130318/1066828)**

Comment: @FahimParkar see `poncha` answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly (which i doubt), You want a way of fetching **additional** top results matching your search criteria, after getting first N...

The major problem with this is that the **new** record (which you show in #3) may go **anywhere** between the previous results, thus making the records you already fetched obsolete (in order).

So, if you really want this, you should do two things:

1. Remember **all** the IDs you already fetched, and in query provide `NOT IN(list of already fetched ids)` in `WHERE` clause, without specifying *offset* (only `LIMIT 2`)
2. After you fetched that, add the amount of the results you fetched anew to the list and reorder it if needed (some sort of insertion sort)

Comment: This solution is correct, but may the IDs I already fetched was too much and need heavy upload traffic from the client. There is a better solution?

Comment: @EmRa228 You can remember the list of IDs on the server (in server-side session storage for instance), and on next request update the list again. However, notice that this approach contradicts base principle of RESTful services - these requests are no longer stateless

Comment: This approach is very intelligently. I also can store in the database. I'll be waiting, perhaps someone gave me SQL statement it.