# PHP and MySQL - sort or group - after the ID

Tags: php, mysql

UPDATE: 30.06.2013

```
$phonesRelated = $DB->getRandom(" `".DB_PREFIX."phones` a, `".DB_PREFIX."phones_categories` b ", " a.id ", " AND a.id=b.phone_id AND b.phone_id!='".$phone['id']."' AND b.category_id IN (".implode(",", $arr).") GROUP BY a.id", 3);
$smarty->assign("phones", $phonesRelated);
```

Hi,

1. `".DB_PREFIX."phones` - represent the table with phones which have more columns (once is ID)
2. `".DB_PREFIX."phones_categories` - represent the table with 2 columns (phone_id[have the same number with ID from `".DB_PREFIX."phones`] and category_id[is the number of the category])

example: we're on webpage iphone3 which have the ID=7 in table `".DB_PREFIX."phones` on column `ID`.

What i need is to make the query return the phones ID after the ID=7 -> ID=8,ID=9,ID=10. At this moment the query returns records by IDs from the end of the table `".DB_PREFIX."phones_categories` which are ID=46,ID=47,ID=48.

Can someone help me with a hint of what to add at the code to make it return the consecutive IDs?

Comment: add `order by` to your sql and order by the name not the ID

Comment: Are you using any aggregating functions?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "aggregating functions" (i don't know to much about PHP and MySQL). The above code works OK, only i can't make it to chose the IDs consecutive (it chose the lastest from table). i found like my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431279/how-can-get-records-after-specific-id-in-mysql but i don't know to put it my code.

Answer (score 2):

Just add to the end of your query:

```
ORDER BY name DESC //Or whatever serves as name
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want them to be in order as in: Iphone5, Iphone4s, Iphone4... or do you not care, as long as it is the same every time?

If the first is the case, then do the previous answer suggested, if not, then you will need to make sure that when you are entering the rows into your table, you do that in the same order every time

Comment: I need to be the same every time. Doesn't matter the version of phone. I wish to be eliminated "random" forver :)

Comment: I think if you do the other suggested answers you will avoid random forever! It will be in order though, but since you don't care, then it should work!

Comment: please show me in the code because i put "order by" at the end of "$sql ..., $str_category ... and $sql = " SELECT * FROM ..." but the same behavior. Can you modify the entire line(s) of code where need the changes. thank you.

Comment: make the edits in your original post so I can see what you've already done

Comment: just to make sure `id` is a column in your table? Also why didn't you add the `ORDER BY` to the first query?

Comment: yes id is a column. if i put ORDER BY at the first query returns "none" (no items found)