# Is AUTO_INCREMENT implemented properly in my case?

Tags: mysql, last-insert-id

This question is bit related to my [**old question, Getting last record from mysql**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923366/getting-last-record-from-mysql).

Per those answers, I learned that ***SELECT is not guaranteed to return rows in any specific order (without using an ORDER BY clause, of course).***

I followed the @YaK answer and added `AUTO_INCREMENT` in table using below commands.

```
ALTER TABLE maxID ADD sequence INT DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE maxID ADD INDEX(sequence);
ALTER TABLE maxID MODIFY sequence INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

However today I got one question.

**When `SELECT` is not guaranteed to return rows in any specific order (without using an `ORDER BY` clause, of course), THEN while altering table, `AUTO_INCREMENT` would be properly implemented?**

Comment: Have you tried to run some tests?

Comment: @GregD : Nope, I got this question while reading the old answer. Also doing test would be tough as I have to manually check each row and there are thousands row...

Comment: Depends how you'd make such tests.  I think (1) create table with AUTO INCREMENT, (2) populate with sample data, (3) drop PRIMARY KEY, (4) create new column with AUTO INCREMENT value, then (5) simple `SELECT col FROM t WHERE col1 != col2` should do the trick.  There might be some differences between InnoDB and MyISAM engines, I think.

Comment: @GregD : Hmm, let me check...

Comment: Adding an AUTO_INCREMENT column will "properly" give you a unique, incrementing value.  Anything beyond that is luck.  If you want to set the values in your preferred order before enabling the AUTO_INCREMENT, then do that.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on Engine type for what is happening in the background:

'For MyISAM and BDB tables you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix. This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.'

This will create tables with multiple values on the auto_increment, non-unique values.

So what you really mean is to have a PRIMARY KEY with auto_increment (though not necessary) for InnoDB tables.  A simple select will return values in the Primary Key order when selecting without a order by clause because it is stored in this order and will use the Primary Key for sorting.

If you want a specific order ALWAYS specify it, use the PRIMARY KEY if you want, but ALWAYS specify it.