# SELECT statement with multiple WHERE criteria (MS-Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

Below is the sample data:

```
c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
1    a1   a     1     1
2    a2   a     2     1
3    a3   a     3     1
4    a4   a     4     1
5    b1   b     1     1
6    b2   b     2     1
7    b3   b     3     1
8    b4   b     4     1
9    a1   c     3     1
```

I want to get the the below details:

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
1    a1  a   1    1
5    b1  b   1    1
9    a1  c   3    1
```

`C1` is primary key, the criteria is for any given unique(c2) where c4 is the lowest, I want to return the contents(all the 5 columns) of the row.

Comment: [What ahve **you** tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) - show us **some effort** then we'll be glad to chip in and help...

Comment: try sub query for multiple where criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT c3, MIN(c4) c4 
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY c3
) t2 ON t1.c3 = t2.c3 ANd t1.c4 = t2.c4
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cea1/3)

**Update:**<sup>1</sup>  In SQL the returned results is a [**set**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) set(unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause, it is a cursor in this case), wherein the order is not guaranteed. This is a standard. You should use an ORDER BY clause if you want to guarantee a specific order. In your case , the results is not guaranteed to be ordered like `1 5 9`. Add `ORDER BY c1` instead.

The `ORDER BY` clause might be crucial in some cases, for example, if want to get the top three rows, or the maximum one, in this case you have to specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

So if you wants to persist a specific order the you have specify an `ORDER BY`.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> As noted by @Fahim Parker, see the comments below.</sup>

Comment: Ok guys hold on for one sec, let me tell you that I want the code that works in MS-Access, sorry I did not mention it in first place

Comment: @aaaabbbb - Its my pleasure. Glad to help.

Comment: please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11130318/1066828). **SELECT is not guaranteed to return rows in any specific order (without using an ORDER BY clause, of course)**

Comment: @FahimParkar - Yes it is true. In SQL the returned results is a [***set***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29), where the order is not guaranteed. This is a standard. You should use an `ORDER BY` clause if you need it to gurantee a specific order. Like in your case with `MAX`. Also in this case, this is true as well, there is no guarantee that the rows returned with a specific order. If the OP wants to persist a specific order he can use an `ORDER BY` clause as well. But what is the problem with my answer with this part.

Comment: as per OP input your answer is right. BUT thought to share my point to OP as input is based on SELECT.

Comment: @FahimParkar - Ok, Thanks for your point. A lot of people are missing this fact.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal : yeah, for small organization this is not that much. for for big database, this point is very much STRONG. Hence I include AUTO_INCREMENT column in my each table (wherever needed) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
from table
where c4= (select min(c4) from table as f where f.c4 = table.c4);
```

i hope that helps

Comment: instead of `select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5` you could have said `select *`

Comment: Could, but there's no better or worse.