# How to select some rows from MySQL table using theirs numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a set of rows (it is actually filtered and ordered mysql table).
I also have a set of integer numbers like (5,9,12,67,2,3) which I want to use as row numbers.

Question: What is better way to fetch rows from this set using these numbers?

Example: I have a set 15 rows. And numbers (1,5,7). How I can get 1st,5th and 7th rows?

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728413/equivalent-of-oracles-rowid-in-mysql) will give you hint.. but why you are playing with rownumber? also [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11130318/1066828)

Comment: @FahimParkar I have a crazy selection algorithm, which should get N random lines from given set of rows. Line numbers generated by special complex algorithm, so I can not use MySQL for it.

Comment: How do you get the set of rows? Is it just a SQL query or are you using some other programming language as well?

Comment: I've tried this code and it looks like works as I am expected.

    select * from (SELECT *, @rowid:=@rowid+1 as rowid FROM `games`, (SELECT @rowid:=0) as init WHERE gametype_id = 10 order by rating desc) t2 where t2.rowid in (1,3,19,27,57,59,161,171,276,686,867,1091,1896,1997,2536,2740)

Comment: @MonadNewb set of rows is just a complex mysql subquery.

Comment: @AlexeyKhaydukov Welcome to Stack Overflow. FYI, you can expedite answers to your question by taking the important parts from your actual code and creating a *complete* example that illustrates what you are asking about. Post the example here along with your question. Just be sure that when someone else runs your example, it recreates the *exact* results that you are asking about and does not introduce any irrelevant errors or side effects that can confuse the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code
    select * from (SELECT *, @rowid:=@rowid+1 as rowid FROM table, (SELECT @rowid:=0) as init WHERE ... order by ...) t where t.rowid in (...set of numbers...)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just singed up and don't know the good habit to answer so I'll try this:

If You have auto_increment index use that?

If not you can make arbitrary number like

```
SELECT @currentRow := @currentRow + 1 AS row_number, *
FROM table, (SELECT @currentRow:=0) as init 
WHERE row_number IN 1,5,7
```

(something is wrong with WHERE)

Yes i got it figured out but @Epsiloncool seemd to do it much faster.

Triple select helps you to get where:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *, @currentRow := @currentRow + 1 AS row_number
  FROM table t, (SELECT @currentRow := 0) AS init) AS table
WHERE cdees.row_number IN 1,5,7
```

Comment: Actually I tested this and it's not working :D and there is also typo "WHERE row_number".

Comment: from @Alexey i realized i was missing the init of currentRow. But still the WHERE is somehow not working.

Comment: yes, I've tried it early, but it will not work, because row_number is counted value which is not available in the where body, but not real column.